# Achieving Two SQL Injection queries at one time (with and without single quotes)

Tags: sql, security, sql-injection

I'm currently stuck with this SQL Injection task.

I am supposed to make the following two SQL queries true, **both at the same time**. I am also only allowed to enter one input which must work for the two statements below. The underlined part is where my input goes into. The assignment is hosted on a web server that receives my single user input.

```
Query 1: SELECT 0x43242a = __;
Query 2: SELECT '0x89222a' = '__';
```

What I've tried:
Using a combination of -- and ; to comment and attempt to create another query, but to no avail. I explored and these two statements successfully trigger ONLY ONE of the statements at each time, even though they seem like they should work for both queries.

The main problem is because the second query expects a single quote, and so it seems like I can never please both queries.

I have tried three scenarios

```
Input: 0x89222a' OR '1' = '1' OR '1' = '1
Query 1: SELECT 0x43242a = 0x89222a' OR '1' = '1' OR '1' = '1; (false)
Query 2: SELECT '0x89222a' = '0x89222a' OR '1' = '1' OR '1' = '1'; (true)
```

^ Somehow, I thought this would cleverly meet both conditions. For the first one, although the first comparison fails, the OR handles the second one which should be true, but it is picking up as false. The second statement however is true.

```
Input (quotes are part of the input) : ' or 1=1 --; SELECT '1' = '1'
Query 1: SELECT 0x43242a = ' or 1=1 --; SELECT '1' = '1'; (true)
Query 2: SELECT '0x89222a' = '' or 1=1 --; SELECT '1' = '1''; (false)
```

^ This makes the first query true, and I would think it'd work for the second, by handling the single quotes for the second query, but nope.

```
Input: 0x43242a--; SELECT '1' = '1
Query 1: SELECT 0x43242a = 0x43242a--; SELECT '1' = '1; (false)
Query 2: SELECT '0x89222a' = '0x43242a--; SELECT '1' = '1'; (true)
```

^ I also tried the above input instead, which makes the second query a true, but unable to make the first one true.

This is a screenshot of how the assignment web page looks like. I do not know the details of the type of database it is running though... I'm not sure if it's because of how they code it that I cannot fully exploit the SQL Injection like how it works? Or would it also work on a website like this?

[Website platform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJcwh.png)

Comment: Are you sure that's the full query?  There's no 'from' clause.  Do you know what DB this is running against?

Comment: Hello! Thank you so much for your response. I've added an image of how it shows on the assignment web page, looks like that is indeed the full query. I do not know the details of the type of database it is running though... I'm not sure if it's because of how they code it that I cannot fully exploit the SQL Injection like how it works? Or would it also work on a website like this? [link](https://i.imgur.com/4iqV6Fn.png)

Comment: Actually - I looked, and several DBs support it the no from clause syntax (although its not ansi).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exact syntax will depend on the DB and how it parses - feels like MSSQL to me based on the semicolon seeming to split statements.  I think you're going down the right track but would stick with the 'OR' clause - the DB will return the last query in a separated list. In the first scenario you're getting issues with the quote parsing.

You might also experiment with escape characters '\' at the end of the string to escape the second quote if it's there.